# Is it possible to access builtins or any other useful functions through an Ellipsis object?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a challenge where I'm given a function where I can pass only a single argument which must be a builtin (no modules of any kind), for example `chr` or `IndexError` and use its attributes and call its functions to get access to other builtin types.

For example, if I choose the `getattr` function, I can access the builtins like this:

```py
def main(a):
    builtins = a(a, '__self__')

main(getattr)
```

Most other functions aren't of much help for my challenge. I know that the attributes are deep and a lot of information can be extracted.
This is a good reference: https://book.hacktricks.xyz/misc/basic-python/bypass-python-sandboxes

What can I get access to using an Ellipsis object, in Python written as `...` ?
Subclasses can be accessed using `....__class__.__base__.__subclasses__()` which returns a list and eventually get access back using a for loop to find which of those classes's `__name__` attribute is catch-warnings, and that class's _module attribute has all the builtins ([Code](https://gist.github.com/luca-m/5130167#file-py-notes-L13)). I cannot use that because the index at which it will appear is always different

The python version I target is 3.9.

Comment: Why `a(a, '__self__')` instead of `a.__self__`?

Comment: Because getattr gets it's own attribute `__self__`. But `a.__self__` would be acceptable in my case